# How deal with loops taking variables as names

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of country' codes such as :

```
country <-c("KHM","CMR","TCD","CHN","COL","CRI","CIV","CUB","DOM","COD","ECU","EGY")
```

Each country have two column representing treir consumption such as "**i**_final consumption P.3h" and "**i**_other consumption P.3n" that I want to sum, I tried the following code but it is not working:

```
for (**i** in country) {
final_demand <- FD %>% mutate(fd_i =  `**i**_final consumption P.3h` +
                                      `**i**_other consumption P.3n`) %>% 
select(fd_i)
df_all_countries <- df %>% mutate(final_demand = fd_**i**) 
}
```

Did someone have a solution?

Comment: Hello. Please share some reproducible data along with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example using `sprintf` and `[[]]` to access the columns in the data.frame and create a new one in a simple for-loop:

```
country <-c("KHM","EGY")

df = data.frame("EGY_sum1"=c(1,2,3,4), 
                "EGY_sum2"=c(4,5,6,7),
                "KHM_sum1"=c(1,2,3,4),
                "KHM_sum2"=c(1,2,3,4)
                )

for (entry in country) {
  
  df[[sprintf("%s_sum", entry)]] <- df[[sprintf("%s_sum1", entry)]] + df[[sprintf("%s_sum2", entry)]]
}
```

The result is then in the two columns KHM_sum and EGY_sum:

```
 EGY_sum1 EGY_sum2 KHM_sum1 KHM_sum2 KHM_sum EGY_sum
1        1        4        1        1       2       5
2        2        5        2        2       4       7
3        3        6        3        3       6       9
4        4        7        4        4       8      11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! Unfortunately on the datafram I use, I get this error message: "Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, sprintf("%s_fd", entry), value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6960"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to reshape your data (using the ‘tidyr’ package) such that the column names no longer contain a variable part:

```
FD <- FD %>%
  pivot_longer(
    ends_with("consumption P.3h"),
    names_to = c("Country", "Which"),
    names_pattern = "([^_]+)_(final|other) consumption P.3h",
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Which)
```

Now your data looks as follows:

```
  Country final other
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 KHM         1     2
2 CMR         3     4
…
```

Afterwards, you can compute `final_demand` without needing a loop:

```
df_all_countries = FD %>% mutate(final_demand = final - other)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste0` to create the variable name together with `get` which allows to pass a string as a variable name:

##### Example data

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(`KHM_final P.3h` = 1:5,
             `KHM_final P.3n` = 6:10,
             `CMR_final P.3h` = 11:15,
             `CMR_final P.3n` = 16:20)
df
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  `KHM_final P.3h` `KHM_final P.3n` `CMR_final P.3h` `CMR_final P.3n`
             <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>
1                1                6               11               16
2                2                7               12               17
3                3                8               13               18
4                4                9               14               19
5                5               10               15               20
```

##### Implementation

```
for (i in c("KHM", "CMR")) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(fd_i = get(paste0(i, "_final P.3h")) + 
             get(paste0(i, "_final P.3n"))) %>%
    print()
}
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  `KHM_final P.3h` `KHM_final P.3n` `CMR_final P.3h` `CMR_final P.3n`  fd_i
             <int>            <int>            <int>            <int> <int>
1                1                6               11               16     7
2                2                7               12               17     9
3                3                8               13               18    11
4                4                9               14               19    13
5                5               10               15               20    15
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  `KHM_final P.3h` `KHM_final P.3n` `CMR_final P.3h` `CMR_final P.3n`  fd_i
             <int>            <int>            <int>            <int> <int>
1                1                6               11               16    27
2                2                7               12               17    29
3                3                8               13               18    31
4                4                9               14               19    33
5                5               10               15               20    35
```

Comment: Hit! Thanks a lot for your answer!! I've been able to run your example, but how I can change the column name "fd_i" such that it takes country code names (fd_KHM, fd_CMR)?

Comment: One way to do it is to rename the variable using `%>% rename_at("fd_i", ~paste0("fd_", i))`